# Garbage string on wordpress websites

Tags: wordpress, string, web

Hi please let me know how this happened on my WordPress website.What will be the root cause?

**Actual characters**
Get the booklet ‘How to
make the most out of your
NDIS’ and you’ll learn…

**Garbagcharactersor**
Get the booklet ÔÇÿHow to
make the most out of your
NDISÔÇÖ and youÔÇÖll learnÔÇª

**Actual CHaracter**

We’re a registered provider of NDIS plan management. That means if you’re struggling to get the providers you need in your area, or are snowed under by the work required as part of self-management, we can manage your plan for you.

— Pick from hundreds more providers
— Have your paperwork taken care of
— Get every cent you’re entitled to

**Garbage character**

WeÔÇÖre a registered provider of NDIS plan management. That means if youÔÇÖre struggling to get the providers you need in your area, or are snowed under by the work required as part of self-management, we can manage your plan for you.

ÔÇö Pick from hundreds more providers
ÔÇö Have your paperwork taken care of
ÔÇö Get every cent youÔÇÖre entitled to

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your encoding is incorrect. You can try commenting out (or uncommenting) these lines in your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Here's a link that goes into a bit more depth on some possible solutions. Somewhere along the way your character encoding got mismatched: https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-foreign-characters-in-wordpress-issue/